Resolve cors error for Nuxt 3, for embedded app making request in project
CORS ERROR
I have an issue in my project, I understand the error, as well as I tried to find answer for it but no luck so far.
Here is my scenario:

I have nuxt 3 app, where I am embedding one of the vue component.
That component is a chatbot, where user can ask some question to it.
I have no control or no way to access method or API call it make to get chat response, which is giving me error as, that api call origin is different.

How can I solve this cors error?
My app is running on localhost:3000 and request are made by that component is something like https://part1.part2.part3.origin.com/log and https://part1.part2.part3.origin.com/api/chat
NOT SURE IF BELOW CODE IS NEEDED OR NOT
I have this config in nuxt.config.js file:
vite: {
    server: {
      proxy: {
        '/APPWEB/': {
          target: 'http://localhost',
          changeOrigin: true,
          secure: false
        },
        '/APPWEB/Lib/': {
          target: 'http://localhost',
          changeOrigin: true,
          secure: false
        }
      }
    }
}

my-component.vue
<template>
    <div>
        <component
          :is="myCMP"
          v-if="myCMP"
          user-type="external"
          env="stg" />
    </div>
  </template>
  <script setup>
  import corsImport from "package-name-import";
  const myCMP = shallowRef(null)
  async function loadComponent() {
    const targetComponent = './component-embedded-vue3'
    const envRemoteEntryMap = {
      dev: 'https://a.b.c.com/mf/remoteEntry.js',
      stg: 'https://a.b.c.com/mf/remoteEntry.js',
      prod: 'https://a.b.c.com/mf/remoteEntry.js'
    }
    if (import.meta.client) {
      try {
        await corsImport(
          /* webpackIgnore: true */
          envRemoteEntryMap.stg
        )
        const myComponent = (await window.myCMP.get(targetComponent))().default
        return myComponent
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    }
  }
  onMounted(async () => {
    myCMP.value = await loadComponent()
  })
  </script>
  

My backend is running on localhost.
What above proxy code is doing is that, for endpoint /APPWEB/ and /APPWEN/Lib/ it will redirect those request to localhost.
I don't have anything in server folder of my Nuxt project.
More Explanation

I have a component in Vue 3, in nuxt 3 project.

I am embedding one of the component, which I have no control, except loading it inside my project, by importing it's package and using it in <Component> element with is attribute.

Now that component is making different API call, which are not allowed on my side, here is those call below.

https://part1.part2.part3.origin.com/country-check

https://part1.part2.part3.origin.com/log

https://part1.part2.part3.origin.com/chat


Error message:

Access to fetch at 'https://abc.efg.haj.company.com' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.


I cannot make below changes, as I do not have control over that component which make api calls.

fetch('/api/country-check')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data));

Please guide me how to solve this issue and if needed please update question title.
Error screenshot



The question is unclear. " I understand the error" - what error exactly? You should do the request to nuxt server in order to avoid cors errors. target: 'http://localhost' - what is the intention of this? This is completely unrelated to what you mentioned previously, you have no /APPWEB/Lib/ mentioned in urls

this is mr project proxy url, not related to that embedded app which making request.

And my backend is running on localhost.

@EstusFlask, its is cors error.

"cors error" is too generic to receive specific solution.  Please provide the exact error.  Copy pasted if you can.

Let me add error screenshot.

@Nexo Sorry, it's still unclear, it needs to be understandable to users who aren't aware of your problem, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask You mention http://localhost (which means http://localhost:80) and it's unknown if you mean localhost:3000, because they are different origins, and it would be a mistake to confuse them. In order to avoid cors errors you need to specify target url (....origin.com/log ?) in proxy target and make requests to the same host as nuxt server (localhost:3000?). Don't do requests to ....origin.com/log directly, a proxy cannot work this way

@EstusFlask, sorry for any confusion, I am also unclear about certain part here, so that is why I am trying to add as much information as needed and also ask top contributor if they can modify my question who understand erro, sorry for confution. Let me try to understand your comment and then update my question. Sorry again...

@Nexo From my understanding, should be proxy: { '/log': { target: 'https://part1.part2.part3.origin.com/' ... in config (no "log" in "target"), make requests to http://localhost:3000/log, etc. If this doesn't work, consider updating the question with relevant info and explaining your case further

Let me try that, to check if it is working or not. If it does not work I will remove proxy party from question, I have added as I thought I need to make some changes there.

@EstusFlask, This is not helping, let me update my question.

I see. Base api url is supposed to be stored in env variables and substituted when necessary. This is how it's normally done. Your options are very limited otherwise. "I cannot make below changes" - consider explaining your case further. Why you can't modify comps in your own app, despite this may be required to make them workable. Whether part1.part2.part3.origin.com is your api provider or some kind of public api you'd like to connect to. And what's the problem with localhost:3000, i.e. whether the problem occurs in production too or just locally. The possible solutions depend on this

So, reason I cannot make any change first, part1.part2.part3.origin.com, is API consumed by my project and not under my control. The component is loaded to my project and I cannot make any change to that component, I can just pass some prop which is needed by component. I don't know about how that component is working behind the seen as I am embedding it.

What about "And what's the problem with localhost:3000, i.e. whether the problem occurs in production too or just locally"? Consider using @, otherwise other users won't receive notifications

@EstusFlask This is spike task, so as of now I cannot check if issue occurs on Production or not. I have reach out to one of senior dev from my team, and he told me that to solve this issue I need to configure contentSecurityPolicy properly in Nuxt config.

If there's no domain of yours that could make requests to part1.part2.part3.origin.com without cors errors then the only option is to fork these comps and fix the urls. The comps were badly designed, this made them unusable, that's the main problem. If they are written with options api then it may be possible to "extend" them and replace some methods instead of copying and pasting entirely, could be easier to maintain them this way depending on their origin. And an extremely hacky workaround is to patch globalThis.fetch to replace these urls with localhost proxy on the fly.

There could be other options, but it's impossible to suggest anything else without seeing the implementation of these comps, and knowing what part1.part2.part3.origin.com exactly is and whether it's possible to have a whitelisted domain for it

Let me see if I can add component code as well, or something that mimic it.

@EstusFlask, I have added code.

Can you clarify what happens here? Is my-component your own component, while the requests to  part1.part2.part3.origin.com are made by component-embedded-vue3 ? How is corsImport implemented?

@EstusFlask, Nomy-component is to store component fetched from remoteEntry.js and return it to use in is variable, component-embedded-vue3 is making those api requests. And for corsImport, I don't know what or how it is doing but this is something https://github.com/ScriptedAlchemy/webpack-external-import/blob/master/src/corsImport.js, I found on wiki that is related to corsImport.

You need to copy https://a.b.c.com/mf/remoteEntry.js locally and fix it to make the requests it makes to work with cors (replace part1.part2.part3.origin.com with localhost:3000). Or if you don't want to do this for some reason, you'll have to fix component-embedded-vue3 on the fly. This would involve creating another local proxy (a.b.c.com->localhost:3000) for remoteEntry.js, replacing part1.part2.part3.origin.com in its response and patching package-name-import to fetch remoteEntry.js from local proxy instead of a.b.c.com. Unnecessarily complicated but still possible
